# instanation of template function on template class

Tags: c++, templates

Given:

```
//hpp
template <typename T>
struct Demo {
    template<typename U>
    U convert(const T &t); 
};

//cpp
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
U Demo<T>::convert(const T &t) {
        return static_cast<U>(t);
}
```

how do I explicitly instantiate the template in the cpp? (e.g. T is double, U is int)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template int Demo<double>::convert<int>(const double &);
```